# Importing MUI Component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As you know, there are 2 ways to import MUI component. For example:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
// or
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
```

So my question is: Which way should I use? And any differences between them?

Comment: Here you go:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447187/is-there-a-difference-between-these-two-material-ui-import-methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will make it short.

**Option 1**

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
```

You can use this in any scenario. The bundler will only bundle the `Button` component to your build files instead of the entire MUI library.

**Option 2**

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
```

Same as Option 1 **IF AND ONLY IF** your bundler supports tree-shaking (this is a technical term, google this if you want to know more). If you are using modern frameworks like Create React App, Next.JS, Gatsby, etc. Then they already support tree-shaking out of the box and the choice is purely preference.

Comment: I use this in React app, so does react support tree-shaking?

Comment: @LXT With what framework? Create React App? There are a lot of ways to create an React application.

Comment: yes, I use create-react-app to create a React app

Comment: @LXT, then you are free to choose any syntax you like. `create-react-app` supports tree-shaking out of the box (unless you are using a very old version of CRA, which is unlikely).

Comment: I got it, thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Importing individual components like `@mui/material/Button` reduces the overall bundle size.  You don't need to import the whole library, just desired components.

[Here is a good resource](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)

Comment: Yes and no. Your answer is partially correct. Named import will not import the whole library if the bundler support tree shaking.

Comment: True..Assuming developer has configured webpack for tree shaking, and then again building in production mode and/or using webpack 5+.