# How to import both default and named from an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

What is the correct syntax to import both `default` and named resource from an ES6 JavaScript module?

Example:

```
export const defaultBrowser = 'Chrome';

export default [
  { value: 0, label: defaultBrowser },
  { value: 1, label: 'Firefox' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Safari' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Edge' },
];
```

How would one `import` that in one go?

---

It is not a duplicate of *[When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281#36796281)*, it is more specific, asking for a single `import` use-case, and not an `import` essay.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The correct syntax to import both `default` and named exports from ES6 module is to pass the `default` name (whatever one wants), and named, not-default modules separated by a comma:

Example: *index.js*

```
import browsers, { otherValue } from './browsers';
```

in an exemplary file tree:

```
.
└── src
    ├── browsers.js
    └── index.js
```

Often encountered real life example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: `import defaultVar, { namedVar1, namedVar2 } from './your-file';` (for anybody who gets confused by the variable naming in the answer)

Comment: *"[exemplary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exemplary#Adjective) file tree"* or *"example file tree"* (there is a difference)?