# ClassName/ClassName.js Module Resolution with Webpack & Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Often times I see the following directory structure and import pattern in Javascript projects:

### ClassName/index.js pattern

```
RepoRoot
|-src
  |-index.js
  |-ClassName
    |-index.js
    |-SupportingClass.js
```

**src/ClassName/index.js**

```js
import { SupportingClass } from './SupportingClass';
export class ClassName {
  // Implementation
}
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import { ClassName } from './ClassName';
```

---

This is all fine and dandy. It allows for a much cleaner import of the ClassName class. However I'm not a fan of the name of the class file `index.js` not having the same name as the class's name. It:

1. Makes it harder to locate the file in a file name search (Command+P in VS Code)
2. You end up with just a very unhelpful `index.js` in the file tab in the IDE (yes I know some IDEs are smart enough to add a bit more context when you have more than one file of the same name open. That helps, but isn't a real solution imo)
3. Other files that aren't the indexes get much more descriptive names: SupportingClass.js, someUtils.js, etc.

### ClassName/ClassName.js pattern

```
RepoRoot
|-src
  |-index.js
  |-ClassName
    |-ClassName.js
    |-SupportingClass.js
```

**src/ClassName/ClassName.js**

```js
import { SupportingClass } from './SupportingClass';
export class ClassName {
  // Implementation
}
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import { ClassName } from './ClassName/ClassName';
```

This solves all of the problems I laid out, but makes the import of ClassName a bit duplicative. Probably not a big deal for most people especially with your IDE being able to auto import things for you nowadays.

### However...

Just how webpack & node.js understand out of the box how to interpret the import path:

- `./ClassName` as `./ClassName/index.js`

Is there a setting or plugin that allows for it to interpret:

- `./ClassName` as `./ClassName/ClassName.js`?

I've been wondering for years if such a thing existed but could never really find any literature on it. Curious if anyone here knows of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with named imports and default imports, more details on this discussion can be found here:

> [How to import both default and named from an ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723020/how-to-import-both-default-and-named-from-an-es6-module)

From your situation (I haven't tried with subfolders, but it should work), you may want to organize your files as such:

```
RepoRoot
|-src
  |-index.js
  |-ClassName
    |-ClassName.js (named module)
    |-SupportingClass.js (named module)
    |-index.js (default modules)
```

And then you can easily import your stuff in **src/index.js** such as:

```
import ClassName, SupportingClass, { otherValues } from './ClassName'
```

Comment: Ah right, I should've mentioned that that's what most people end up doing to achieve this. But I'm really looking for a solution that doesn't involve having to maintain an unneeded index.js file in every directory.

Comment: If you don't need default modules, you can use just named one, go ahead and try deleting index.js file from ClassName subfolder and remove the , { otherValues } from your import statement.