# Why is import/export statement not working?

Tags: javascript, import, export

So I have these two files:

foo1

```
const a = 2;
export {a};
```

and

foo2

```
import a from "./foo1.js";
console.log(a);
```

both files have been made module files with the html:

```
    <script src='./scripts/foo2.js' type='module'></script>
    <script src='./scripts/foo1.js' type='module'></script>
```

As soon as the script runs it throws this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './foo2.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Comment: Check out what [export default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript) means.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module

Comment: If `import a from "./foo1.js";` is how you want to import it, then you need to export it as `export default a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are importing works only with default export/import.
So there are two ways you can fix your code:

1. **changing the import statement**

`import a from "./foo1.js";`

(Not using default exports)

2. **changing the export statement**

`export default a;`

Then while importing you can do anything, because the default export is still `a`:

`import a from "./foo1.js";`
`import aWithNewName from "./foo1.js";`

Comment: The second solution worked but could you elaborate on what you mean by "The way you are importing works only with default export/import"?

Comment: Also, with the second solution, I then ran into the issue where if I make a different variable and export that, it will only export the default instead.

Comment: You are doing `import a from ...` . Here `a` will be the default import only because there are no curly braces. Now since there **was no default export**. Hence the issue

Comment: In the second situation if you want to import more than one variable you will have to do `import aDefault , { bNotDefault, cNotDefault }`. Note how the default variable can be without braces, rest all have to be inside. Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723020/how-to-import-both-default-and-named-from-an-es6-module

Comment: The first solution also worked thank you, I had no idea that the curly braces made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you to export from `foo1` there's no need to add both js files, you need only the file where you want to import. Try this way:

```js
// foo1.js
export const a = 2;

// foo2.js
import { a } from "./foo1.js";
console.log(a);
```

```html
 <script src='./scripts/foo2.js' type='module'></script>
```