# Error with reduxjs/toolkit - cannot dispatch an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am learning react, specifically with reactjs/toolkit for this section, and am going through a few basic examples to help teach myself where I am faking someone logging into their account. I understand the issue of my error but I cannot figure out how to solve it. As far as I can see my code is completely correct because my previous examples have followed the exact same pattern. The issue comes from my authSlice when it is imported. In the source file, it has access to authSlice.actions.login etc, but once imported it does not. For whatever reason it does not register login(){} or logout(){}. So when I attached the form to my submission handler this error is thrown. I think this is the issue because when I console log the actions I do not see my login or logout actions. I could also be wrong on this too, but I will attach the actual error at the end

I have my store in a separate file as follows:

```
const intialAuthState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialState: intialAuthState,
    reducers: {
        login(state) {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
        },
        logout(state) {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        },
    },
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {counter: counterSlice.reducer, auth: authSlice.reducer}
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export default store;
```

and my auth component is as follows:

```
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import classes from './Auth.module.css';
import authActions from '../store/index';

const Auth = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(authActions);

  const loginHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    dispatch(authActions.login());
  };

  return (
    <main className={classes.auth}>
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={loginHandler}>
          <div className={classes.control}>
            <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
            <input type='email' id='email' />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.control}>
            <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
            <input type='password' id='password' />
          </div>
          <button>Login</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

I am pretty new to react so I am a bit confused here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full Error:

```
Auth.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: _store_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.login is not a function
    at loginHandler (Auth.js:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396:1)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507:1)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413:1)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889:1)
loginHandler @ Auth.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: _store_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.login is not a function
    at loginHandler (Auth.js:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396:1)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507:1)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413:1)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889:1)
loginHandler @ Auth.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
VM925:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (index.js:1:1)
4043 @ VM925:2
r @ VM925:2
8048 @ VM925:2
r @ VM925:2
8641 @ VM925:2
r @ VM925:2
(anonymous) @ VM925:2
(anonymous) @ VM925:2
(anonymous) @ VM925:2
e.onload @ index.js:1
be @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
load (async)
be @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
t @ index.js:1
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
error (async)
o @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
ge @ index.js:1
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:45
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:851
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ index.js:56
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:851
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that your import

```
import authActions from '../store/index';
```

is doing a default import, which is the `store`. You want to do

```
import { authActions } from '../store/index';
```

---

For more info see: [How to import both default and named from an ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723020/how-to-import-both-default-and-named-from-an-es6-module)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. Such a simple solution and I knew it was some sort of issue with the import but could not for the life of me figure it out! I will accept the answer when the time limit passes

Answer (score 0):

it's bad practice to set actions with reducer
you have to create a file named Actions.js an you can declare function as actions and export them also create a file named store.js for

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {counter: counterSlice.reducer, auth: authSlice.reducer}
});
```

do it like this :

```
const intialAuthState = {
    isAuthenticated: false
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialState: intialAuthState,
    reducers: {
        login(state) {
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
        },
        logout(state) {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        },
    },
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {counter: counterSlice.reducer, auth: authSlice.reducer}
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export store;
```

and Auth component:

```
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import classes from './Auth.module.css';
import {authActions} from '../store/index';

const Auth = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(authActions);

  const loginHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    dispatch(authActions.login());
  };

  return (
    <main className={classes.auth}>
      <section>
        <form onSubmit={loginHandler}>
          <div className={classes.control}>
            <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
            <input type='email' id='email' />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.control}>
            <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
            <input type='password' id='password' />
          </div>
          <button>Login</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am pretty new to all of this and have only worked on personal projects so I don't know the best practices of stuff like this