# How to use a Function Import Inside another Function which is a export Function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and learning about it. While I was learning about Named and Default Exports I ran into an issue. I am not sure how to explain my doubt in words here is my code.

namedExport.js

```js
const name = "xyz";
const age = 20;

const myFunc = () => {
    const name = "abc";
    const age = 21;
    return (<>
    <h2>{name} is {age} years old.</h2>
    </>);
}

export {name, age}
export {myFunc}
```

defaultExport.js

```js
const myFunction = () => {
    const name = "ijk";
    const age = 22;
    return (<>
    <h3>{name} is {age} years old.</h3>
    </>);
}

export default myFunction
```

App.js

```js
import { name, age, myFunc } from "./namedExportTest";
import myFn from "./defaultExportTest";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi Everyone</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Exports() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="exportNamed">
        <h1>My name is {name}, I am {age}.</h1>
      </div>
      <myFunc />
      <myFn />
    </>
  );
}

export {Exports};
export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Exports} from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Exports />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I am not getting the Expected Output.
My Expected Output:

```
Hi Everyone //in h1 tag
My name is XYZ, I am 20. //in h1 tag
abc is 21 years old. //in h2 tag
ijk is 22 years old. //in h3 tag
```

But the output I got is:

```
Hi Everyone //in h1 tag
My name is xyz, I am 20. //in h1 tag
```

I am not sure what the mistake I did. If anyone knows what mistake I made, please post it with the Code Example to get my Expected Output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that React component names must start with a capital letter, so `myFunction` should be `MyFunction`, and `myFunc` should be `MyFunc`. I get your desired output when fixing this capitalization issue in both the component files and the file importing the components.

By the way, you are importing from `./namedExportTest` and from `./defaultExportTest`; however your files are called `namedExport.js` and `defaultExport.js`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default exports and named exports in a same file, you have to import them in a single line in the index.js file.

```js
import App, {Exports} from './App';
```

[How to import both default and named from an ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723020/how-to-import-both-default-and-named-from-an-es6-module)