# Navigate ES6 throught cTags

Tags: javascript, vim, ctags

My [.cTags](https://gitlab.com/tarunsharma20/dotfiles/blob/master/ctags/.ctags) is working fine in mostly cases. However in a scenario mentioned below it's not working as expected.

**Directory Structure**

```
root
 - a
   - foo.js
   - bar.js
   - index.js
 - b
   - current-file.js
```

**current-file.js**

```
import { foo } from './a'

foo()
```

**index.js**

```
export { default as foo } from './foo'
```

**foo.js**

```
const foo = () => 'foo'

export default foo
```

When i am trying to jump in definition of `foo` from **current-file.js** its navigating to **a/index.js** instead of **a/foo.js**

Comment: Shouldn't you import `{ default as foo } from './foo'` instead of export?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not a limitation about the cTags, but about the ES6 language itself.

The curly braces import will first lookup for the file named `a`, if not found, it will look for the directory named 'a' with its `index.js` file (auto-resolved, e.g: `a/index.js`). It won't look for a file into a directory.

The curly braces are only looking for the non-default exports from a file, and it's not looking through directories.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-knuth-0wf89?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Findex.html&moduleview=1) (NOTE: the directory `a` has been renamed to `c` as codesandbox reserved the name `a` in his engine)

You can try to remove the `/c.js` file to load the `c/index.js` file instead.

Also, I suggest you [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/3397563) which can give you more tips on curly brackets in js

You might be able to do a read through a directory with the [fs.readDir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) api and automatically `require`/export the files in your `index.js`; But the `index.js` will be loaded.