# why I have to export const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and ES6, still struggling in understanding its syntax, below is an example code from my book:

```
import React from 'react';

export const App = () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>

export default App;
```

but why I have to use 'const' as well, why I can't do like;

```
export default App = () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>
```

it compiled but caused an runtime error,which I don't know why, I always can do the following without any errors:

```
export default function (…) { … }
```

I'm really confused

Comment: You *can* use `export default`, but default exports aren't named, so you'd have to remove the `App =` part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: @CertainPerformance   but what about `export default App;`, isn't that also named?

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in naming default export because when you are importing it, you can import it as anything

```
export default () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>

// can be imported as
import Foo from './App';
import Bar from './App';
import AnythingYouCanThinkOf from './App';
```

If you want named import:

```
export const App = () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>

// can be imported only as
import { App } from './App';
```

Also please note that there can be multiple named exports but only one default export in a single file.

```
export default () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>
export const Header = () => <div>Header</div>
export const Footer = () => <div>Footer</div>
export const Sidebar = () => <div>Sidebar</div>

// imports
import AnyNameYouWantWhichIsDefaultExport, { Header, Footer, Sidebar } from './App'
```

Comment: so why with const, I can do named import?

Comment: Because it's the way it works, is the name of your export. You don't have to use const, you could also export function Header() { } for named export.

Answer (score 0):

You can just export `default`, but default exports do not enforce names on import.  So, the code would look like this:

```
export default () => <h1 className="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">
  Hello Adam
</h1>
```

Comment: but what about `export default App;` in the example,  isn't that also named?

Comment: no, `App` refers to the function.  So, it is not named.  You do not import a default export based on a name:  `import App from './App';`.  the name `App` in the import could be anything: `import Anything from './App';`

Comment: for `export default App = () => {...}`, isn't that App also refer to the function?

Comment: default export has a name: `default`

Comment: @secondimage after `export default` needs to be a value. `=` makes it a statement which is invalid

Comment: @marzelin default export does not enforce a name on import.

Comment: yes but you can import it by its name: `import {default as sth} from "./somewere.js"`. It has a name.

Comment: @secondimage a function can be passed in JavaScript.

Comment: @marzelin  after reading all comments, I found your answer makes the most sense,.

Comment: @secondimage one more bit that might interest you: if you put `App = () => {...}` in parentheses it will be valid

Comment: @marzelin   so for `export const App = () => {...}`, can I understand in this way:  `const App = () => {...}` will be executed first, then `export App` executes, just a compiler trick?

Comment: @secondimage it's not a compiler trick, it's a specification rule. Compilers, or rather language engines, can work any way they want as long as they conform to language specification.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to export a **default** value, you want to import it without name (name it exactly when you import it somewhere else) somewhere else then you can't just **export default** it with name so to export default you can do the following:

```
// Just export it
export default () => ...

// Or this way
const App = () => ...

export default App;
```