# ios _reactnativereanimated.default.Value is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

[IOS_Error_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueqq6.png)I am new to react native. I am trying to include drawer navigation inside my react app but I am not able to do it.
I followed each and every steps provided in the documentation. But still I am getting the below error, can you tell me how to fix it providing my code snippet and sandbox below.
I researched and found the below error but still not helping me

ios _reactnativereanimated.default.Value is not a constructor

[TypeError:Undefined is not an object while trying an animation in ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966380/typeerrorundefined-is-not-an-object-while-trying-an-animation-in-reactnative)

Providing my code snippet and package.json below

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Animated, { Value } from 'react-native-reanimated'


function Feed({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Open drawer"
        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
      />
      <Button
        title="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Notifications() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Close drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Toggle drawer"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      useLegacyImplementation
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "FCC",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "android": "react-native run-android",
      "ios": "react-native run-ios",
      "start": "react-native start",
      "test": "jest",
      "lint": "eslint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
      "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
      "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
      "react": "17.0.2",
      "react-native": "0.68.2",
      "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.1.0",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
      "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
      "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
      "react-native-maps": "^0.31.1",
      "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
      "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
      "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
      "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "7.18.0",
      "@babel/runtime": "7.18.0",
      "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
      "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
      "eslint": "7.32.0",
      "jest": "26.6.3",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.67.0",
      "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I have updated all the packages to the latest one. But before doing this, check whether your other functionality will not affect by updating the packages.
I am also providing the commands to update all packages.

1. npm i -g npm-check-updates
2. ncu -u
3. npm install

Hope this will help you.