# Named export / unnamed export

Tags: reactjs

I currently follow this tutorial here which uses:

```
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from '../constants'
```

While I followed the tutorial step-by-step I have to use

```
import AUTH_TOKEN from '../constants'
```

My constants.js looks like this:

```
export const AUTH_TOKEN = "auth-token";
```

I struggle to understand why my React.js app behaves the opposite.

Comment: `import AUTH_TOKEN from` is for default exports. `export const AUTH_TOKEN` isnt a default export, so `import { AUTH_TOKEN } from` has te be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: What error do you see when you use `{ AUTH_TOKEN }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from '../constants'    
export const AUTH_TOKEN = "auth-token";
```

this means that there are more than one to export..
but if you changed the code like this:

```
export default const AUTH_TOKEN = "auth-token";
```

so you can make your import like this:

```
import AUTH_TOKEN from '../constants'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is called named import and named export

```
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from '../constants' // importing in file A
export const AUTH_TOKEN = "tokenValue"    // exporting from file B
```

In above method you use {} and **same name** for import and export

```
import  MY_AUTH_TOKEN  from '../constants' // importing in file A
export default const AUTH_TOKEN = "tokenValue" exporting from file B
```

In above method you do not use {} and name does not matter.

Find the good [read](https://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) for understanding the concept further.