# Creating Object with Constructor in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to create an RN Object with a constructor passing json object but I'm getting "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Product".

**Product.js**

```
export default class Product {
    constructor(product) {
        this.name = product.name
        this.items = product.Items
        this.price = product.Price
        this.productID = product.ProductID 
        this.medias = product.Medias
        this.imageSmall = BASE_IMAGES_URL + product.MediaSmall
        this.imageLarge = this.getImageLarge(product.Medias)
    }
}
```

**PDP.js**

```
import { Product } from '../models/Product'
class PDP extends Component {
 render() {

    var imagesProd = [];
    var product = new Product(this.props.navigation.state.params.currentProduct);
      ....
}
}
```

the problem is with `new Product()` using directly `this.props.navigation.state.params.currentProduct`works fine.

**EDIT**

After your tips, I changed the import to `import Product from '../models/Product'`but I'm getting

> TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a
>   constructor (evaluating 'new P.default(s)')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your import. You used a default export in Product class so your import should be

```
import Product from '../models/Product'
```

Comment: thanks! I changed the import but now I'm getting other error. (EDITED with more details)

Answer (score 0):

The first line in PDP.js should be `import Product  from '../models/Product'`

Take a look here for few details about import.
[When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: thanks! I changed the import but now I'm getting other error. (EDITED with more details)