# react-icons and react Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-icons

## Context

i'm designing a navigation bar for my application and my proyect uses **react-router** and **react-router-dom** for managing routing and **react-icons** for icon retrieving.

## Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MdAssessment } from 'react-icons/md'
import Styles from './NavBar.module.css' 

const NavBar = (props) => {

    return (
        <nav className={Styles.navBar}>
            {navIcon}
            <NavLink
                activeStyle={{ color : 'red' }}
                className={`${Styles.navBar__Dashboard} `}
                exact to="/">
                <MdAssessment />
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink
                activeStyle={{ color: 'red'  }}
                className={Styles.navBar__Requests}
                to="/requests">
                Requests
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink
                activeStyle={{ color: 'red'  }}
                className={Styles.navBar__Tasks}
                to="/tasks">
                Tasks
            </NavLink>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

## Problem

I'm trying to extrapolate *activeStyle* functionality of NavLink to my icon.
Given that react-icons provides you with component as icons, i'm struggling with which approach should i use:

1. Should i wrapped in a HOC?
2. Should i encapsulate in a custom Hook?

### Notes

I've tried with both approaches but can't get my head arround it. I've tried implementing **useRef**, **useEffect** while reading to *location* with **useLocation** hook as well.
Any suggestion for a better implementation of a generic **NavIcon** feature taking this context into account?

Comment: I just tested react-icons on my sandbox,
you can see it here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-use-react-router-dom-4cvov?file=/src/components/Nav.js) and the icons take on the active color. Maybe the problem comes from your CSS.

Comment: Yeah, i know. I can inherit some properties (if not all) from the father. My issue here is trying to give a totally different style from their parent component.
I actually tried by passing the icon componente with extra props, but it didn't feel right

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By using curly brackets you are importing the icon as a named import. So the import only works if the file contains a named export of the same name you have assigned it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import) for more info.

According to the [package documentation](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/), this is the correct way to import an icon. Can you check to make sure the named export is the same as you have imported?

Comment: Taylor, i have no trouble visualizing the icon, my concern is that i want to "activeSyle" it as i can with the Navlink. I actually did it before implementing react-icons, i hardcoded material-icons className and just rendered a text. In my public HTML file i imported martial icons CDN. 
I'm now trying to achieve the same, but with react icons, icons are actually components  so icons appear to be now children of my NavLinks.