# How can I import javascript module without ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, node-modules

I made an export Javascript file like following:

```
export const A = 1;
export const B = 2;
export const C = 3;
```

And, I try to import that to another Javascript file like following:

```
import 'path/export_file.js'
console.log(A); // ReferenceError: A is not defined
```

I know I can fix it if I do the following:

```
import A from 'path/export_file.js'
// or
import { A, B, C } from 'path/export_file.js'
```

But I want to use like `import 'path/export_file.js'`
Some modules just do `import'path/file'` and I can use all of exported from that module.

What should I do?

Or am I mistaken for something?

Comment: Not possible unless the module assigns to global properties, which should really be avoided since it defeats the whole point of a module system. You should use `import { A, B, C } from 'path/export_file.js'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things to know:

1. You should know about Import/Export default & named in ES6
2. As @CertainPerformance's mention, you have to use {} unless the module assigns to global properties.

   `import { A, B, C } from 'path/export_file.js`
3. In case of mix both `Default` and `Named`, you can use `*` like this

   `import * as Mix from 'path/export_file.js`

Thanks [@prosti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41927090/9071943) with a great answer.

[image]