# Not able to use useState()

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error every time I try to use react hooks in my funtiom:

> TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default is not a
> function or its return value is not iterable

Following is my code:

```
import './RouteDetails.css';
import useState from 'react';
...
...
..


export default function RouteDetails() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


    return(
        <div>       
                    <Row className="route-details-heading">
                        <Col className="d-none d-sm-block" md={4}><b>Route Name</b></Col>
                        <Col className="d-none d-sm-block" md={4}><b>Difficulty</b></Col>
                        <Col className="d-none d-sm-block" md={1}><b>Length</b></Col>
                        <Col className="d-none d-sm-block" md={1}><b>Time</b></Col>
                    </Row>
        </div>
    )
 }
```

React and React-dom is of the same version. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Also, I am not using jest

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/2873538) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_single_export_from_a_module).

Comment: The default export from `"react"` is conventionally named `React`, it's not the hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing `useState` like `import { useState } from 'react'`. It is not a default.