# Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I am trying to use https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html as follows:

```
import O, {Option} from "fp-ts/Option";
....

useEffect(() => {

    if (error) {
        handleResultCategories(O.none);
        return;
    }
    handleResultCategories(O.some(selection));
}, [error, selection]); 
....
```

the compiler complains:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined
    at http://localhost:6006/main.22489267b0e89682c1e1.hot-update.js:130:82
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate
```

Changing to:

```
....
import {Option, some, none} from "fp-ts/Option";

useEffect(() => {

    if (error) {
        handleResultCategories(none);
        return;
    }
    handleResultCategories(some(selection));
}, [error, selection]);
....
```

it works. What is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: maybe there's no default export?

Comment: Indeed, no default export https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Comment: And as a quick supplement: A default import is not just an object containing all of the named exports. In order to use it that way, the package you're using has to have implemented it. It's not how it works by default.

Comment: You could however use this: `import * as O from 'p-ts/Option';` to accomplish that syntax.

Comment: Try enabling the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option in your `tsconfig`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports