# how to resolve this error element type is invalid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

Here's my `App.js` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './Components/Logo/Logo';
import Imagelinkform from './Components/Imagelinkform/Imagelinkform';
import Rank from './Components/Rank/Rank'
import Facerecog from './Components/Facerecog/Facerecog';



const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: '391e77688a1e40ceaf6264a70543fcc5'
 });


const particlesOptions={  
    particles: {
    number:{
      value:30,
      density:{
        enable:true,
        value_area:800
      }
    }
        }
      }
    

  class App extends Component { 
  constructor(){
    super();
      this.state={
        input:'',
        imageUrl:''
      }
  }
  onInputChange=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  onButtonSubmit=()=>{
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    app.models
      .predict( 
        Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,
        this.state.input)
        .then(
          function(response){
            console.log(response.outputs[0].data.region[0].region_info.bounding_box)
          },
          function(err){

          }
        )
  }
render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Particles  className='particles'
              params={particlesOptions}
               />
   <Navigation/>
   <Logo />
   <Rank />
   <Imagelinkform onInputChange={this.onInputChange} onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}/>
   
  <Facerecog imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl} />
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I suspect the problem is with one of the components `App` tries to render, not `App` itself. Please **reduce** the problem to a [mcve], ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by export and import of JS files in your `App.js`. Make sure you're doing something like in this your app

```
// SomeFile.js

const SomeFile = () => {
....
....
}
export default SomeFile //Default Export
```

Now in your App.js

```
import SomeFile from './SomeFile' // Correct Way
import {SomeFile} from './SomeFile' // Wrong way for default import
```

An image from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import) for better understanding
[image]