# Getting Error while using useState() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

[why this error comes, check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jvcd.png)

when i am trying to use state in my react component, this error comes and i dont know how to solved it, i also have googled it but i dont found any solution.

this is my code below

```
import useState from 'react';
import ExpenseForm from './ExpenseForm';
import './NewExpenses.css';

const NewExpenses = (props) => {
   const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

   const saveExpenseDataHandler = (newExpenseData) => {
      const expenseData = {
         id : Math.random().toString(),
         ...newExpenseData
      }
      props.onCreateExpense(expenseData);
      setIsEditing(false);
   };

   const startEditingHandler = () => {
      setIsEditing(true);
   };

   const stopEditingHandler = () => {
      setIsEditing(false);
   };

   return (
      <div className="new-expense">
          {!isEditing && (
              <button onClick={startEditingHandler}>Add New Expense</button>
          )}
          {isEditing && (
              <ExpenseForm
                  onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseDataHandler}
                  onCancel={stopEditingHandler}
              />
          )}
      </div>
  );
};

export default NewExpenses;
```

**Thanks In Advance...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your importing **useState**:

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 1):

Like MHP said: you are importing `useState` without curly braces. This only works if `useState` was exported from `"react"` as a default export, which is not the case. The default export from `"react"` is `React` while `useState` is a named export. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import) answer for more info.