# What does it mean by import 'something' instead of using import something from 'something'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

What does it mean if you import something like this :

import 'something';

thats it. instead of using it like this :

import x from 'y'

I saw it while watching a tut on firebase;
it was like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

How does the last three lines work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Answer (score -1):

The following statement imports the *default export* from Firebase package

```
import firebase from "firebase"
```

The other 3 are imported for their side-effects only which *"runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values."*

If you notice you don't use import and use anything from those packages. All Firebase services are accessed using the `firebase.` namespace such as:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const auth = firebase.auth()
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Now if you remove `import "firebase/auth"`, the Auth SDK won't be initialize (whatever it does under the hood) and the `firebase.auth()` statement might throw an error that looks like:

> firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.auth is not a function

You can read more about imports at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only).