# Element type is invalid: expect a string

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use an `AppBar` from [React Native Material](https://www.react-native-material.com/docs/components/app-bar). The icon i use in the `IconButton` is from [react-native-vector-icon](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/). I have no idea why I'm getting error saying **Element type is invalid: expect a string. Check the render method for IconButton** as I literally copied the exact code from the `React Native Material` official doc.

```js
import {AppBar, IconButton} from '@react-native-material/core';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';

      <AppBar
        title="Title"
        leading={props => (
          <IconButton
            icon={props => <Icon name="menu" {...props} />}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

==> Try My Code it works.

```
import {AppBar, IconButton} from '@react-native-material/core';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';

      <AppBar
        title="Title"
        leading={props => (
          <IconButton
            icon={props => <Icon name="menu" {...props} />}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: It works now.. I don't see any difference from my code but it works somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @Leo WelCome, Please approve my answer and upvote me for motivation.

Comment: @Leo the difference is the `Icon` is not a component inside `react-native-vector-icons/Entypo` it's the default  export so, when importing don't use curly braces : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/10657559

Comment: @ZFlocTechnologies Thank you for the clarification! Didn't know that till now, thanks!