# Is this the right way to create a global const variable?

Tags: node.js, constants, global

I am trying to create global const variables and I am wondering if this is the good way?

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')
Object.defineProperty(global, "db", {
    value: new sqlite3.Database(__dirname + '/database.db')
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can global constants be declared in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174552/can-global-constants-be-declared-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

"Do NOT use global variables! If you start running your application with multiple processes you will get screwed very badly."

In order to use a globally accessible variable, you sould use a module.

eg:

In a file named `db.js`

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3'); 
exports.current = new sqlite3.Database(__dirname + '/database.db');
```

To use it:

```
const db = require('./db.js'); // instanciated only once
db.current.all("SELECT * FROM playlists", [], (err, rows) => {
   if (err) {
      throw err;
   }
   rows.forEach((row) => {
       console.log(row.name);
   });
});
...
```

Refer to another answer of the same
[How to use global variable in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987444/how-to-use-global-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: sure. but my question was if this is the right syntax for creating one?