# How Can I Access A Constant Variable With Only A String

Tags: javascript, scope, constants

I have the following issue:

```
const value1 = "some value";
var   value2 = "some value";

console.log(window["value1"]); // undefined
console.log(window["value2"]); // some value
```

I know that const is block scoped and that is the reason I cannot access it through the window object. My question is, is there any way to access a const variable using only a string identifier.

If all I have access to is "value1", how do I get a handle on the actual value1? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure If I can use eval for this, but I would rather not use eval.

Comment: Yes, you could use `eval`, and yes you should not do that. Why not simply do `console.log(x == "value1" ? value1 : …)`? Why do you even *need* to access local variables by string, why don't you use an appropriate data structure (like a `Map` or an object)?

Comment: If you must use a string to access a variable like that, why not just use an object? `const constants = { value1: "some value" };` Then you can get it using `console.log(constants["value1"])`.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174552/can-global-constants-be-declared-in-javascript

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that's exactly what I did. I will use this for the time being. I'm still curious if it's possible, but probably not since it's block scoped. This may have been a hasty question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, block scope declarations, like let and const, are not added to the global object, meaning you can not access them through a property of window.

See this related question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776236/10965456

eval should work `eval("values1")`, as well as the Function constructor `new Function("return value1")()`, though I'm not sure why this is necessary. If you need to dynamically access certain values, use an array, object, or map instead.

Comment: Hey, that new Function("return value1")() method is pretty good. Do you know if it is very similar to eval? Of course, that's creating a function just to return the constant variable, which is probably not very efficient. Still, this has answered my question. This is another way to access a block scoped variable using a string.

Comment: The Function constructor is considered a form of eval when it comes to content security policies - and for good reason - passing unsanitized input to it can lead to arbitrary code execution. Adding script to the DOM can do the same thing.

Comment: Some info about eval and Function when it comes to security and performance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!

Comment: @Frank The `Function` constructor only works for global `const`/`let` variables, not for local block-scoped ones. And yes, it's very much the same as `eval` - don't use it.

Comment: I did get it working for const variables in the global scope, but I think what I will use is an object like so: `{ "value1":value1 }` I am loading object constructors from a JSON file, so I have them in string format. I just need to get a handle on the actual constructor.

Comment: Probably the correct idea. Using an object or a map is ***far*** better than dynamically creating code.