# Use dynamic variable with array map react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to print an Array whose name is being calculated based on selected value.
e.g.

```
const ANotes = ["B", "C", "D"];
const keyNotes = MyNotes[selected] + "Notes"; //value is ANotes
```

Trying to render it as:

```
<View>
        {{keyNotes}.map((item, key)=>(
         <Text key={key} 
          //style={styles.TextStyle} 
          //onPress={ this.SampleFunction.bind(this, item) }
          > { item } , </Text>)
        )}
      </View>
```

When I try to render it in View in my Component it gives error. I'm new to React Native so not able to figure this one. I want the output to show B, C, D in the App.

It gives error: TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a string value to access a variable in the local scope without it being attached to some object or array check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926156/7645069) for some solutions

Seems you're using functional component if you switch to a class component you can then access it with `this[keyNotes]`

```
<View>
     {this[keyNotes].map((item)=><Text key={item}> {item}Notes,  </Text>)} 
</View>
```

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wildflower-jnffx?file=/src/App.js) (I'm using react not react-native so I changed to dom eelments)

Comment: keyNotes is the selected value that holds the string ANotes. I used this as an example.

Comment: What do you mean the "string ANotes"? ANotes is an array. And what's MyNotes?

Comment: MyNotes[selected] evaluates to "A" which makes keyNotes evaluate to "ANotes". It's mentioned in the code snippet comment part.

Comment: So KeyNotes is the string 'ANotes'?

Comment: Yes. So if I use keyNotes to fetch array values of ANotes. What should be the exact syntax?

Comment: Oh I don't believe that's possible without attaching it to an object or array and accesing it like so `ArrayName[KeyNotes]` check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926156/7645069 for some other solutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215675/discussion-between-moshe-sommers-and-pulkitgulati).