# Working around IE8's broken Object.defineProperty implementation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ecmascript-5

Consider the following code, using ECMAScript5's `Object.defineProperty` feature:

```
var sayHi = function(){ alert('hi'); };
var defineProperty = (typeof Object.defineProperty == 'function');
if (defineProperty) Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sayHi',{value:sayHi});
else Array.prototype.sayHi = sayHi;
var a = [];
a.sayHi();
```

This works for Chrome and Firefox 4 (where `defineProperty` exists), and it works for Firefox 3.6 (where `defineProperty` does not exist). IE8, however, [only partially supports `defineProperty`](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). As a result, it attempts to run the `Object.defineProperty` method, but then fails (with no error shown in the browser) and ceases to run all other JavaScript code on the page.

Is there a better way to detect and avoid IE8's broken implementation than:

```
if (defineProperty){
  try{ Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sayHi',{value:sayHi}); }catch(e){};
}
if (!Array.prototype.sayHi) Array.prototype.sayHi = sayHi;
```

*For the curious, I'm using this in my [ArraySetMath](http://phrogz.net/JS/ArraySetMath.js) library to define non-enumerable array methods in those browsers that support this, with a fallback to enumerable methods for older browsers.*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way than a direct feature test with try/catch. This is actually exactly what IE team itself recommends in this recent post on [transitioning to ES5 API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx).

You can shorten the test to just something like `Object.defineProperty({}, 'x', {})` (instead of using `Array.prototype`) but that's a minor quibble; your example tests exact functionality (and so has less chance of false positives).

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Browserify with the package pluralize from npm which uses Object.defineProperty and I dropped this in.

https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/es5.js

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this before. IMHO using a try…catch statement is too drastic.
Something more efficient would be to use conditional compilation:

```
/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version>5.8)if(document.documentMode>8)@*/
Object.defineProperty && Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sayHi',{value:sayHi});
/*@end@*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind issue (i.e. the Object.defineProperty in IE 8 being DOM only and not a full implementation as the other browsers), but it was for a polyfill..

Anyhoo, I ended using a 'feature' check to see if I was using IE, its not perfect, but it works on all the tests I could do:

```
if (Object.defineProperty && !document.all && document.addEventListener) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sayHi',{value:sayHi});
} else {
    Array.prototype.sayHi = sayHi;
}
```

as IE <= 8 has no `document.addEventListener`, and `document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the W3C standard. These two checks are equivalent to checking if IE is version 8 or below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.sayHi = function(){ alert('hi'); };

try {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sayHi', {
    value: Array.prototype.sayHi
  });
}
catch(e){};
```