# Object.defineProperty for IE

Tags: javascript

```
var o = {}; // Creates a new object
```

Example of an object property added with `defineProperty` with a data property descriptor

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {value : 37,
                               writable : true,
                               enumerable : true,
                               configurable : true});
```

How to implement for IE7-8?(with attributes writable,enumerable,configurable)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility) there is (almost) no support in IE before IE9.

Comment: You can't, not really... read [check the list here](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), and [check this question, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819693/working-around-ie8s-broken-object-defineproperty-implementation) for some extra info

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Object.defineProperty) {
        Object.defineProperty = function (obj, prop, descriptor) {
            if (arguments.length < 3) { // all arguments required
                throw new TypeError("Arguments not optional");
            }

            prop += ""; // convert prop to string
            ...
```