# Servicestack-SwaggerUI crashes on IE<10 for method "defineproperty" not found

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, servicestack, swagger-ui

I'm using SwaggerUI over a Servicestack v4.07(licensed) application to expose REST specs.

Everything works on Firefox and Chrome, but when i try to open the swagger index with IE9 or below, it crashes, showing nothing but the page header, so no service is listed.

Actually i can reproduce this but even on the swagger demo website http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/

When i open it with **IE9** it crashes because of a (probably) known issue: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/pull/204.

When i open it with **IE8** instead the fiddler tells me that there's no such **defineProperties** method for the Object class(exception raised from *shred.bundle.js*)

Does someone know about such issues?

Comment: Which version of ServiceStack?

Comment: @esker i just edited. BTW i've seen that i have Servistack v4.07 but Servicestack.Api.Swagger v4.0.9.

Comment: Object.defineProperty is indeed not implemented in older versions of IE: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603812/object-defineproperty-for-ie) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175290/object-defineproperty-alternative-for-ie8). I think this should be raised as an Issue in the [Swagger-UI GitHub repo](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui).  I don't have a answer at the moment for how to fix this in the short term with ServiceStack. Swagger UI has never had good support for older IE versions.