# I get error on object - meteorjs iron-router internet explorer 8 (ie8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, meteor, iron-router

I have the latest iron-router and meteorjs.

Everything is working perfect except in internet explorer 8. My target to support are at least ie 9 & 8. Every other browser is working perfectly including ie 9, except ie 8.
I'm getting this error:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

File: 192.168.137.21:3000

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.

File: 192.168.137.21:3000

SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

File: iron_middleware-stack.js, Line: 440, Column: 1
```

And when i click to "File: iron_middleware-stack.js, Line: 440, Column: 1" it gets me to this.

```
Object.defineProperty(MiddlewareStack.prototype, "length", {
  get: function () {
  return this._stack.length;
  },

  writeable: false,
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: true
  // X ERROR: Object doesn't support this action
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug in `iron:router` caused by IE8. [I would suggest lodging an issue on their github (if there isn't already one).](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues)

[There's another stack overflow question which looks at `Object.defineProperty` in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819693/working-around-ie8s-broken-object-defineproperty-implementation)

[Also the MDN page is always useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Thank you i reported the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this issue to iron-router community and it is now solved in version 1.0.3 thanks to them