# text input box does not show up in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html

I found this awesome jQuery "Tag it!" plugin to suggest suggest the keywords and enter with space or comma. Here is demo http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html
However on Internet Explorer the text input box does not show up. Any idea what is problem and how to fix it? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Haven't tested but try not using const, and replace it with this suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript

Comment: @Pointy IE 9, and i think previous versions as well.

Comment: OK I see it now - sorry I had to fire up a VM ...

Comment: almost positive @Eric has the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

That "tag-it" JavaScript code is using some non-standard (Mozilla?) syntax, like those `const` declarations at the top.