# JavaScript constants | Style and keyword

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there constants in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript)

For example here I set the close time on this menu to 1 second or 1000 milliseconds.

```
menu.menu_timer=window.setTimeout(menu.hide_menu, 1000);
```

Does javascript have a const like C or a Define like PHP to define Constants?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/130396/497356

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Update 2017

ES6, or ECMAScript2017, comes with the support for [constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) using the keyword `const`.

While some use camelCase syntax for the constant's names, it still is perfectly valid to use the capitalized (snake_case) version (e.g. `const VARIABLE_NAME;`)

---

### Original answer

JavaScript does not have constants.

You could use the convention of all uppercase for constants.

```
var PI = 3.14;
```

or you could wrap it in an object.

```
window.CONSTANTS = {
   PI : 3.14
};
```

Comment: its better to explain your scope.

Comment: Since ECMA script 6 you can use 'const' to define constants.

Answer (score 4):

The standard convention for constants in JavaScript is to use all uppercase like

```
var MY_CONST = 1000;
```

There is a [const keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Constants) but I believe it is not supported in IE

Comment: `const` is supported in IE 11+