# Does jQuery support constants?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constants

According to [Are there constants in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript) Javascript does not have constants.

Does jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean something like 'Does jQuery have a facility to emulate or implement constants'? You might want to update your question if that is the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery is just a library written in javascript.  It is NOT a separate language.

As such jQuery does not have any more language features than plain javascript.

That said, jQuery does have some predefined values that you can use with various functions.  For example, if you are using the `.fadeIn()` method, you can call it as `.fadeIn("slow")` because `"fast"` and `"slow"` are special strings that the `fadeIn()` method recognizes.  jQuery tends to just use strings like that rather than define `jQuery.SLOW` or something like that which might look more like a predefined constant in other languages.