# JS analysis tool for automatically checking for things (like const) that break in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, build-automation, static-analysis

I recently noticed and fixed a pretty bad JS bug in our software, affecting all IE versions, that was caused by a simple mistake in a .js file:

```
const foo = "..."
```

Now, [IE doesn't support const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript); it's a syntax error. `var` should be used instead. (The offending keyword was actually inserted unwittingly by IntelliJ IDEA's "introduce variable... -> introduce constant" refactoring.)

Our automated Selenium tests are run with Firefox *on Linux*, and getting them running on IE would probably be too much hassle right now.

Anyway, my question is, **is there any static JS code analysis tool** that

1. would have caught the `const` bug (and similar common problems), and
2. can be easily triggered from a CI tool (Jenkins) against certain .js files in a codebase?

[I am aware of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#JavaScript) JSHint, JSLint and Google Closure Tools, but I don't know if any of them meets my criteria above.

Answer (score 1):

JSHint or JSLint would have caught the error in time. You can [configure IntelliJ](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/05/lint-your-javascript-with-jslintjshint-in-real-time/) to show these kind of issues realtime. There is a [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/boxuk/jslint-jenkins-plugin) available as well. I hope you find those useful. :)