# Can we freeze an object without using Object.freeze() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to freeze below object without using `Object.freeze()` is it possible to do so ?

```
const obj = {
  a:'test',
  b:'Something'
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason to not use `freeze()`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement alternative to Object.seal, Object.freeze, Object.preventExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387077/implement-alternative-to-object-seal-object-freeze-object-preventextensions)

Comment: @JakenHerman Just out of curiosity !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Object doesn't support method 'freeze'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117771/javascript-object-doesnt-support-method-freeze)

Answer (score 3):

Not literally, no. `Object.freeze` sets the [*integrity level*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-setintegritylevel) of the object to `frozen`, which you can't do in another way.

You can do *most* of the things that make an object "frozen" separately, though, by using `Object.preventExtensions` to prevent properties being added and the combination of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `Object.defineProperty` to prevent properties being modified or removed. I don't think you can prevent its prototype being changed via `Object.setPrototypeOf`, though, which is another aspect of frozen objects. (You could interfere with setting the `__proto__` property inherited from `Object.prototype` [if the object inherits from `Object.prototype`], but that wouldn't have any effect on `Object.setPrototypeOf`.)

But you can't actually set the integrity level of the object like `Object.freeze` does.

Comment: is it possible to freeze object without using any pre-defined function's of JS ?

Comment: @Aniket the answer states that it's not possible.

Comment: @Aniket - No, `Object.freeze` is the only way to actually freeze an object. And you can't even get close without them. For instance, you can't define a non-configurable property without one of the `Object` methods.