# const handler = function (event) = SCRIPT1002: Syntax error (IE10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, constants, handler

We're boggling our ind over a syntax error that obstructs a [calculating script](http://pastebin.com/BL0WnnxA) in IE10 and below. It traditionally works fine in every other browser.

The error says:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error (line 11, char 12)
const handler = function (event) {
```

Anyone has an idea where things get wrong please?

Comment: Did you try it without const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found out that when I replace `const` with `var` in this script,  the error is solved and that the script runs ok.

Answer (score 2):

[const was new in IE11, it is not supported in IE10.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fconst#Browser_compatibility)

Consider using the ALL_CAPS convention to show that the variable should not be changed. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript)

```
var HANDLER = function (event) {
```