# Why React uses functions as variables?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting started with React and I'm wondering why they choose to use this notation:

`const counter = (state, action) => {}`

instead of the old-traditional:

`function counter(state, action){}`

I'm wondering if that's because of the `const` keyword. Because it is not possible to create a `const function` as it (as stated there: [Are there constants in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript))

is that the only reason? I understand that `const` functions are important in React, to ensure the behavior isn't changed at runtime. But I wonder if that's the only reasons why they choose to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a personal choice, it is new `ES2015` feature called [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

```
const counter = (state, action) => { }

// you can also define counter like this
const counter = function (state, action) { }
```

The main difference is that [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not have its own [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_arguments)