# Jquery issue on safari

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker. And when I select the start date, then in end date automatically gets filled in another field to the next date. I just cannot figure out why I am getting it. The code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but in Safari console, it's giving me an error. Any idea why I might get.

SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '[' instead

The Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 search_date">
        <label>{{lang('start_date')}}</label>
        <input type='text' name="start_date" id="start_date"  value="<?php echo @$start_date; ?>" required=""/>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo @$error['start_date']; ?></span>
        <input style="border:0;" type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" required=""  class="" value="<?php echo @$start_time; ?>"  />
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo @$error['start_time']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 p-t40">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/web/arrow-right.png') }}" class="m-t40">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 search_date">
        <label>{{lang('end_date')}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" required="" class="" value="<?php echo @$end_date; ?>" />
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo @$error['end_date']; ?></span>
        <input style="border:0;" type="text" name="end_time" id="end_time" required=""  value="<?php echo @$end_time; ?>"  />
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo @$error['end_time']; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#start_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            minDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
        });
    <?php if (isset($start_date)) { ?>
        $('#start_date').val('<?php echo @$start_date; ?>');
    <?php } ?>
        $('#end_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            minDate: moment().add(2, 'days'),
        });
    <?php if (isset($end_date)) { ?>
        $('#end_date').val('<?php echo @$end_date; ?>');
    <?php } ?>
        $("#start_date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            const[day, month, year] = $('#start_date').val().split("-");
            var strt_dt = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
            var ultimate = strt_dt.setDate(strt_dt.getDate() + 1);
            var d = new Date(ultimate);
            $('#end_date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(d);
        });

        $('#end_time').datetimepicker({
            format: 'H:m',
        });

        $('#start_time').datetimepicker({
            format: 'H:m',
        });

    });
    $(document).on('change', '#start_date, #end_date', function () {
        $('#end_date').attr('min', $('#start_date').val());
        $('#start_date').attr('max', $('#end_date').val());
    });
</script>
```

I am getting another problem only on Safari console which is :
SyntaxError: Expected token ')'

And here is my following code:

```
<script>
    function alertbox(heading = null, meassage = null) {
        if (heading != null && meassage != null) {
            $('#alert_heading').html(heading);
            $('#alert_message').html(meassage);
            $('#alert_model').modal('show');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default parameters from ES2015 are not yet supported in Safari. [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters)

you can use the following ES5 to let this working

replace you js function with given below to keep this working.

```
 function alertbox(heading, meassage) 
 {
    if(heading  === undefined)
    {
            heading  = null;
    }
    if(meassage === undefined)
    {
        meassage  = null;
    }
   if (heading != null && meassage != null) 
    {
       $('#alert_heading').html(heading);
       $('#alert_message').html(meassage);
       $('#alert_model').modal('show');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit it worked. Can you please look my first problem too.

Comment: what is the line number, you are getting in console for first problem

Comment: Line number is ":8000/:922" which is "const [day, month, year] = $('#start_date').val().split("-");"

Comment: use  the constant like this `const MY_CONSTANT = "some-value"`

Comment: reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript

Comment: const CONSTANT_NAME = $('#start_date').val().split("-");

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
 function alertbox(heading = null, meassage = null) {
                        if (heading != null && meassage != null) {
                            $('#alert_heading').html(heading);
                            $('#alert_message').html(meassage);
                            $('#alert_model').modal('show');
                    }
                    }
```

to

```
 function alertbox(heading, meassage) 
 {
    if(heading  === undefined)
    {
            heading  = null;
    }
    if(meassage === undefined)
    {
        meassage  = null;
    }
   if (heading != null && meassage != null) 
    {
       $('#alert_heading').html(heading);
       $('#alert_message').html(meassage);
       $('#alert_model').modal('show');
    }
 }
```

Safari not allow the assignment like this in function,

Comment: Thanks MJ it worked. Can you please look my first problem too

Comment: @Lalit Onclick  just copied my answer and Irfan YOU knew.. you select my answer first and after removing that you checkd lalits ans why?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. But Lalit gave me complete solution of my problem and you gave partial answer. Please look at the comments too. But I thanking you again for your all efforts.